# Ввод чисел с клавиатуры

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Здавствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать диалоговое окно куда пользователь мог бы вводить только числа с клавиатуры?

Comment: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Спасибо. Но я немного другое имел в виду что-то типо диалога messagebox.show(), но чтобы пользователь мог вводить туда данные. Например, для отрисовки линии смог ввести координаты x1,x2,y1,y2

Comment: Ну поместите текстбокс в окно, добавьте кнопку и текстблок. Вот вам и диалог.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, что так можно)

Comment: Можете примерно показать  как это выглядит?

Comment: @user222355:  Что именно?

Comment: Как будет выглядеть данное диалоговое окно можете показать?

Comment: А как вы хотите чтобы оно выглядело? Всё зависит от вашей фантазии

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подключите в проект [Nuget-пакет Extended.Wpf.Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit).

Приведу пример создания окна на основе [IntegerUpDown](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown&referringTitle=NumericUpDown-derived%20controls), вы можете использовать любой другой контрол из пакета, который вам больше подойдет. Для ввода строк можно использовать штатный TextBox, при этом подключать пакет не потребуется.

Добавьте новое окно (Window), я назвал его у себя `MyDialogWindow`.
Код разметки:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MyDialogWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="Title" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        MinHeight="132" MinWidth="300"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="CaptionBox" Text="Caption"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="ValueBox" Value="10"
                            Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5"/>

        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="2" Rows="1"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <UniformGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,3"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </UniformGrid.Resources>
            <Button Content="OK" IsDefault="True" Click="OkClick"/>
            <Button Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

"Застраничный" код MyDialogWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MyDialogWindow : Window
{
    public MyDialogWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ValueBox.Focus();
    }

    private void OkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = true;
    }

    public static int? ShowBox(string caption, string title = "", int defaultValue = 0)
    {
        var dialog = new MyDialogWindow
        {
            CaptionBox = { Text = caption },
            Title = title,
            ValueBox = { Value = defaultValue }
        };
        var dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
        return dialogResult == true ? dialog.ValueBox.Value : null;
    }
}
```

Всё!

Пользоваться можно, например, так:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var value = MyDialogWindow.ShowBox("Введите значение:");
    if (!value.HasValue)
    {
        // Была нажата кнопка отмены или крестик
    }
    else
    {
        // Значение введено и нажата кнопка ОК
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже реализовал))

Comment: Ну так опубликуйте своё решение и примите ответ, чтобы топик не висел открытым.

Comment: Хорошо, сделаю.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь в код окна такой `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

А вот обработчики:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
     foreach (char ch in e.Text)
        if (!char.IsDigit(ch)) {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
}

private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Key == Key.Space) e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="graphics_editor.Window_draw_line"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:graphics_editor"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Отрисовка линии" 
    Height="220" 
    Width="300"
    MinHeight="200"
    MinWidth="300"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
    FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=leftMarginTextBox}">
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <TextBox Name="ittem_x1" 
             Background="PaleGreen"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Margin="65,7,72,0" 
             Height="25" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
    </TextBox>

    <Label 
        Content="X1: " 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="25"
        FontSize="12"
        Margin="20,7,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="28"
        Background="White" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    </Label>

    <Label Content="Y1: " 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Background="White" 
           Height="25" 
           Margin="20,37,0,0" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="28">
    </Label>

    <TextBox x:Name="ittem_y1" 
        Background="PaleGreen"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="65,37,72,0" 
        Height="25" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
    </TextBox>

    <TextBox x:Name="ittem_x2" 
        Background="PaleGreen"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Margin="65,68,72,0" 
        Height="25" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top">
    </TextBox>

    <Label 
        Content="X2: " 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="25"
        FontSize="12"
        Margin="20,68,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="28"
        Background="White" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    </Label>

    <Label Content="Y2:" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Background="White" 
           Height="25" 
           Margin="20,98,0,0" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="28">
    </Label>

    <TextBox x:Name="ittem_y2" 
             Background="PaleGreen"
             Grid.Row="0" 
             Margin="65,98,72,0" 
             Height="25" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
    </TextBox>

    <Button Name="okButton" 
            Click="okButton_Click" 
            IsDefault="True" 
            Margin="65,138,167,10"
            Content="OK">
    </Button>

    <Button x:Name="cancelButton" 
            IsCancel="True" 
            Content="Cancel" 
            Margin="168,138,47,10"
            Click="Cancel_click">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Код XAML:

```
public partial class Window_draw_line : Window
{
    public Window_draw_line()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /*
     * Ок
     */ 
    void okButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int x1, x2, y1, y2;
        x1 = Convert.ToInt32(ittem_x1.Text);
        x2 = Convert.ToInt32(ittem_x2.Text);
        y1 = Convert.ToInt32(ittem_y1.Text);
        y2 = Convert.ToInt32(ittem_y2.Text);
    }

    /*
     * Cancel
     */ 
    void Cancel_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что если юзер введёт не число?

Comment: Спасибо, фильтры забыл добавить. Код отредактирую, скину

Answer (score -1):

```
private void Draw_line(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LineGeometry MyLine = new LineGeometry();
        Window_draw_line dlg = new Window_draw_line();
        if(dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            MyLine.StartPoint = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(dlg.ittem_x1.Text),
            Convert.ToInt32(dlg.ittem_y1.Text));
            MyLine.EndPoint = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(dlg.ittem_x2.Text),
                Convert.ToInt32(dlg.ittem_y2.Text));
            Path myPath = new Path();
            myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;
            myPath.Data = MyLine;
            t.Children.Add(myPath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: И как это отвечает на вопрос? Если у вас новый вопрос, задайте его новым вопросом.

Comment: Это код по использованию окна в mainwindow