# Получить данные от окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Возникла необходимость создавать окно для ввода названия файла который позже будет создан. Создать окно несложно, но как от этого окна вернуть данные я не могу придумать. Есть ли способ определить произошло ли событие `Click()`? Или подскажите более грамотные или разумные способы. Буду рад даже направлению в котором искать.

Код создаваемого окна:

```
class InputBox : Window
{   
    //private static  InputBoxDialog;
    private static TextBox textBox;
    private static Button button;
    private static Label label;
    private static Window NewWindow;
    private static Window CurrentWindow;
    private static string TextVar;

    public InputBox()
    {

    }
    public InputBox(ref Window textVar)
    {
    }

    public void Show(string labelContent)
    {
        CreateBox(labelContent);
    }

    public void Show(string labelContent, string titleContent)
    {
        CreateBox(labelContent, titleContent);
    }

    public void Show(string labelContent, string titleContent, string buttonContent)
    {
        CreateBox(labelContent, titleContent, buttonContent);
    }

    private void CreateBox(string labelContent, string titleContent = "Input Box", string buttonContent = "Enter")
    {
        NewWindow = new Window();
        NewWindow.Name = "NewWindow";
        NewWindow.Title = titleContent;
        NewWindow.Width = 300;
        NewWindow.Height = 200;
        var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        label = new Label { Content = labelContent, Name = "NewWindowLabel" };
        textBox = new TextBox { Text = "", Name = "NewWindowTextBox" };
        button = new Button { Content = buttonContent, Name = "NewWindowButton" };
        button.Click += NewWindowButton_Click;
        stackPanel.Children.Add(label);
        stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
        stackPanel.Children.Add(button);
        NewWindow.Content = stackPanel;
        NewWindow.Show();
    }

    private void NewWindowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextVar = textBox.Text;
        NewWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

Вызов этого окна:

```
public void GetFileName()
{
    var InputBoxMsg = "Enter you file name";
    InputBox inputBox = new InputBox();
    inputBox.Show(InputBoxMsg);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704250/218063

Comment: Для ввода имен файлов лучше использовать специальные штатные диалоговые окна Windows

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться потернам MvvM. Для WPF он больше подходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по описанию вопроса вам нужно диалоговое окно, следовательно вам нужно его отображать как диалог

```
NewWindow.Content = stackPanel;
NewWindow.ShowDialog();
```

А дальше вы уже сохраняете информацию в приватное поле `TextVar`.

```
private static string TextVar;
```

значит остается только изменить его на публичное свойство, которое и будет отвечать за возвращение результата или если все сделать в одном методе.

Я немного изменил ваш код - убрал избыточные методы `Show` - при наличии параметров по умолчанию при вызове можно указывать только обязательные параметры а также все или часть из тех, для которых определены стандартные значения. Кроме этого убрал конструкторы, так как в данном случае они не нужны.

```
public class InputBox
{
    public static string Show(string labelContent, string titleContent = "Input Box", string buttonContent = "Enter")
    {
        var NewWindow = new Window();
        NewWindow.Name = "NewWindow";
        NewWindow.Title = titleContent;
        NewWindow.Width = 300;
        NewWindow.Height = 200;
        var textVar = "";
        var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
        var label = new Label { Content = labelContent, Name = "NewWindowLabel" };
        var textBox = new TextBox { Text = "", Name = "NewWindowTextBox" };
        var button = new Button { Content = buttonContent, Name = "NewWindowButton" };
        button.Click += (s, e) => {
            textVar = textBox.Text;
            NewWindow.Close();
        }
        stackPanel.Children.Add(label);
        stackPanel.Children.Add(textBox);
        stackPanel.Children.Add(button);
        NewWindow.Content = stackPanel;
        NewWindow.ShowDialog();
        return textVar;
     }
}
```

и тогда вызов будет следующим

```
public string GetFileName()
{
    var InputBoxMsg = "Enter you file name";
    return InputBox.Show(InputBoxMsg);
}
```

Но это по-прежнему WinForms подходят, WPF способ - определить специальную VM, в которой хранилась бы информация о указанном файле.

Comment: Описанный вами вариант был уже испробован мной. Значение переменной возвращается раньше чем срабатывает событие. В данном случае возвращается пустое поле. А что касается "избыточных" методов Show их я использовал в качестве перегрузки метода, и также вынес логику и вычисления в скрытый метод.

Comment: @KemalAbdullaev вы уверены, что поменяли вызов?

Comment: @KemalAbdullaev предлагаю перейти в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) чтобы быстрее разобраться в причинах. Пожалуйста, сделайте мне пинг когда у вас будет время. Чтобы сделать пинг поставьте собачку @ и дальше мой ник (можно только первую часть)

Comment: Да вы правы. Я не изменил вызов. Если вызывать через ShowDialog() то все работает. Спасибо.